# Arrastrar archivo en Srping Tools (y crear la ruta dentro de HTML)

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Arrastrar archivo en Srping Tools (y crear la ruta)
Se puede arrastrar un archivo sea CSS, JS lo que fuere desde el árbol de proyectos a un archivo HTML?? Por ejemplo en NetBeans se puede sin problemas; tipo... tenes un archivo CSS de Bootstrap y lo arrastras hasta el HEAD de tu HTML y ya tenes el estilo. ¿Se puede hacer eso en STS?
Saludos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, implementar un CSS en html no tiene nada que ver con spring, se implementa igual, escribiendo esto:

```
 <link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ahora, si lo que quieres es un archivo CSS de BootStrap, Spring ya trae algunos archivos de CSS de BootStrap, estos se implementan así:

```
<link href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Y se utilizarían así:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                    class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Miempresa.com</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Si toca Inicio lo enviamos a list.html --> 
                <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
                 <!-- Si toca Nuevo Empleado, no hacemos nada, puesto que ya estamos en ese html -->
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Nuevo empleado</a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <!-- Esto es de bootstrap, para que haya un menú desplegable -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span th:text="${#authentication.name}">Menú</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">                      
                        <li>
                            <!-- Si se pincha se llama al form de abajo -->
                            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Salir</a>
                        </li>                   
                    </ul>
                </li>       
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

De hecho si te vas a tu proyecto de Spring, a:

Maven Dependencies/.jar de BootStrap/resources/webjars/bootstrap/version/css

puedes ver los recursos que trae